# Which method is used in Magento Enterprise 1.14.2.1 to send new order emails

Tags: magento-enterprise, order-email, send-mail, magento-ee

I am using

```
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Gateway has authorized the payment.');

    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
    $order->setEmailSent(true);
```

in my success method, but in Enterprise store the method is not working.
I am not receiving mail for new order.

Can anyone please guide me for this. I am stucked debugging the issue from last two days. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, configure cron on Magento.

Now order emails are sent using cron.

Comment: Thanks for the answer RiccardoT..  Can you guide me how to configure cron on Magento? 

I have seen in forums that crons needs to be set, but not getting a working solution.

Comment: The fastest way IMHO is to install a module named AOE_Scheduler and follow its instructions. It is easy to do.